# Getting customerId and product id from order object in observer?

Tags: product, magento2, observers

In an observer I want to get the product id and customer id from order object... how can I get in Magento 2?

I am not able to get it from the order object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here got answer

```
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); 
    $items =$order->getAllVisibleItems();
    //product ids
    $productIds = array();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $productIds[]= $item->getProductId();
    }

    //custoemr id
    $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
```